# Location and UseCase for AggregateItemReader

Tags: java, spring-batch

[Appendix Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/listOfReadersAndWriters.html) lists a reader `AggregateItemReader` but I am not able to find it in any of Spring Batch jar files. I am using spring batch with spring boot and have version 3.0.7.

[API Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.html) indicates it in samples package.

Currently, I am using `JdbcPagingItemReader` in my project but I want reader to return a `List` or `Collection` of objects to processor instead of a single object.This is needed so I can process those objects in bulk instead of processing one by one.

Pagination requirement is mandatory so I use `JdbcPagingItemReader`

By reading description, it looks `AggregateItemReader` was the candidate but can't find its implementation.

Any Ideas? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package org.springframework.batch.sample.domain.multiline containing AggregateItemReader class seems to be in the spring-batch-samples artifact; this should be also imported into your project separately from spring-batch-core. E.g. in maven pom.xml the following dependency resolves the issue

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-batch-samples</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is it OK to use something from Spring samples for a production application?

Comment: You should probably clarify that with your employer/customer

Comment: I simply used that reader as reference to write my own similar reader but I feel pivotal should specify that in their docs if some of their code is production ready or not.