# Spring Batch - How to make multi threaded Reader, Processor and Writer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-stream

### What is the requirement?

I'm using the Spring batch application for Bulk File Processing.

Steps:

1. Reading the file using network calls.
2. Preparting **a** bulk JSON Payload and calling endpoint.
3. Writing responses to files.

### What is going wrong?

Everything is going well, however is very slow. Usually taking a small file with 25K records 16 minutes to process with below steps:

1. When the reader calls the Processor it blocks and awaits.
2. Once the response gets ready then block again for write operation using slow IO.

Suppose:

1. The time taken for reading and preparing for JSON: 2s  [READER]
2. The time taken for requesting: 2s  [Processor]
3. The time taken for writing: 1s  [Writer]

```java
Single Threaded Block Calls: READER --> Processor --> Writer. //Total 5 seconds per request.
```

### How I want to process?

Multi-Threaded Block Calls:

```
          |- - > Processor - -> Writer.
READER -->|- - > Processor - -> Writer.
          |- - > Processor - -> Writer.
```

Configurations used:

```java
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = transactionManager();
    StepBuilder stepBuilder = new StepBuilder("CARD TRANSFORMATION", jobRepository);
    return stepBuilder
        .<List<FileStructure>, CardExtractOutputList>chunk(1, transactionManager)
        .reader(generalFileReader.reader(""))
        .processor(cardExtractFileProcessor)
        .writer(cardExtractFileWriter)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .faultTolerant()
        .retryLimit(3)
        .retry(RuntimeException.class)
        .build();
  }



  @Bean(name = "jsob")
  @Autowired
  Job cardExtractFilejob(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    JobBuilder jobBuilderFactory =
        new JobBuilder("somename", jobRepository)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(preJobListener)
            .listener(postJobExecution);
    return jobBuilderFactory.flow(step1(jobRepository)).end().build();
  }


  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
    return asyncTaskExecutor;
  }
```

Custom Reader:

```java
  @Bean
  @StepScope
  @SneakyThrows
  public MultiLinePeekableReader reader(
      @Value(FILENAME_JOB_PARAM) final String fileName) {
    FlatFileItemReader<FileStructure> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>() {};
    final String gcsLocationOfFile =
        FilesUtility.getAbsoluteGCSPathOfAFile(fileName, gcsRelatedConfiguration);

    final Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource(gcsLocationOfFile);
    itemReader.setResource(resource);
    itemReader.setName("FileReader : " + fileName);
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    itemReader.setStrict(true);

    MultiLinePeekableReader multiLinePeekableReader = new MultiLinePeekableReader(fileName);
    multiLinePeekableReader.setDelegate(itemReader);
    return multiLinePeekableReader;
  }

  private LineMapper<FileStructure> lineMapper() {
    DefaultLineMapper<FileStructure> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
      ..
    return lineMapper;
  }
}
```

MultiLinePeekableReader:

```java
public class MultiLinePeekableReader implements ItemReader<List<FileStructure>>, ItemStream {
 private SingleItemPeekableItemReader<FileStructure> delegate;
..
  @Override
  @SneakyThrows
  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public synchronized List<FileStructure> read() {
    List<FileStructure> records = null;
    int readCount = fileProcessingConfiguration.itemsPerRead();
    try {
      for (FileStructure line; (line = this.delegate.read()) != null; ) {
        seqNo = seqNo.add(new BigInteger(FileProcessingConstants.NUMBER_STRING_ONE));
        line.setSequenceNo(seqNo.toString());
        line.setMaskedSensitiveData(
            FilesUtility.getMaskedSensitiveDataFromData(
                line.getSensitiveData(),
                fileProcessingConfiguration.leadingPersistCount(),
                fileProcessingConfiguration.trailingPersistCount()));

        if (readCount == fileProcessingConfiguration.itemsPerRead()) {
          records = new ArrayList<>();
          records.add(line);
          readCount--;
        } else {
          records.add(line);
          readCount--;
          FileStructure nextLine = this.delegate.peek();
          if (nextLine == null || readCount == 0) {
            readCount = fileProcessingConfiguration.itemsPerRead();
            return records;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (FlatFileParseException parseException) {
      if (records == null) {
        records = new ArrayList<>();
      }
      ..
    } 
    return records;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
    this.delegate.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    this.delegate.open(executionContext);
  }

  @Override
  public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    this.delegate.update(executionContext);
  }

  public void setDelegate(FlatFileItemReader<FileStructure> delegate) {
    this.delegate = new SingleItemPeekableItemReader<>();
    this.delegate.setDelegate(delegate);
  }
```

Answers already read but didn't found helpful:

[Spring batch single threaded reader and multi threaded writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245655/spring-batch-single-threaded-reader-and-multi-threaded-writer)

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The concurrency model you are looking for is not possible in Spring Batch as it is currently designed. The two single-JVM scaling options are multi-threaded steps, or partitioned steps.

If you really want something like you suggest, you need to provide a custom `ChunkProcessor` that is concurrent, but it will be up to you handle fault-tolerance and restartability.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud thanks for your valuable answer, I am curious if we can use the async processor and async writer here.

Comment: Async processor/writer falls under multi-threaded steps, but still not what you are describing. With async processor/writer, only the processor is run concurrently, the writer just unwraps `Future`s from the processor when ready and writes item in serial.