# Use FlatFileItemReader to read a List of elements

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch

Let's say, I have an object **Engine**, the only attribute is *brandName*, I then have a CSV file as below:

```
car_brand; bike_brand; airplane_brand; boat_brand
brand1;    brand2;     brand3;         brand4
brand5;    brand6;     brand7;         brand8
brand9;    brand10;    brand11;        brand12
```

What I want to do, is reading the CSV file and creating a List for each row.

Since my project is a Spring batch project, I want to use a Reader, but how can I do it?

I tried to do:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Engine> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Engine> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Project>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("file.csv"));
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Project>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(***);
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Project>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Engine.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return reader;
}
```

Usually you create only one object with the reader, how can I create List with the Reader?
Should I change the method type to < List< Engine>>?

---

**EDIT:**
My question is not how to make a Reader of a List, but how to make a FlatFileItemReader of a List, the duplicate question is not the answer I needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a item reader to return a list instead single object - Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929641/making-a-item-reader-to-return-a-list-instead-single-object-spring-batch)

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine I don't think they are duplicate, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following:

```
@Bean
LineMapper<List<Engine>> lineMapper() {
    return new LineMapper<List<Engine>>() {
        @Override
        public <List<Engine>> mapLine(String line, int lineNum) throws Exception {
            String[] tokens = line.split(";");
            if (tokens.length < 1) {
                throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("Expecting at least one token in input line: " + line);
            }
            List<Engine> data = new ArrayList<Engine>;
            for (String token : tokens) {
                data.add(Engine.of(token));
            }
            return data;
        }
    };
}
```

....

```
FlatFileItemReader<List<Engine>> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
```

Comment: I'll make the method of and check if it's works, thanks for the help